# GitLab Merge Train - PreMerge Pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We currently have Merge Train disabled and whenever there is an MR, there is a pre-merge validation pipeline and post merge deployment pipeline.

So, people can approve and merge only after validation succeeds and then stuff goes to deployment, to keep the branch green as much as possible.

We are now doing a POC on using MergeTrains as we cant do parallel deployments in our SaaS. Post merge, stuff gets deployed at once which seems fine.

Is it possible to consolidate the premerge validation pipelines too?